# Protect App files from accessing

Tags: android

I want to play some videos ( 50MB ) inside my android app, i wrote codes to download it to Sdcard.The path is found through

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

My problem is the video can be copied by the user or by other apps.Is it possible to create a private folder which cannot be accessed by user or other apps ?

I tried to create a **.nomedia file** , But still user can access the file.

Answer (score 1):

Download the video to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getCacheDir()`).